# is it correct to compare like if(null == object) or if(object == null) in java

Tags: java

I am working in a project there is a statement like below

```
if(null == object)
{
//do something
}
```

is it same as

```
if(object == null){
// do something 
}
```

Give some example so that both are same or different .

Comment: They are the same since both need to be evaluated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The operator `==` is symmetric.

`x == null` is equalent to `null == x`. But using the first way is more readable and habitually.

There are other ways to check for null value in the object:

```
1. boolean Objects.nonNull(Object obj) // obj != null
2. T Objects.requireNonNull(T obj) // checks out obj and returns it if it isn't null
```

---

Example:

```
String v = "value";

System.out.println(v == null ? null : v);
System.out.println(null == v ? null : v);
```

Output:

```
value
value
```

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference in this specific case. Matter of style. The first style is  [Yoda style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) of coding usually write to avoid null pointer. But this case, it's the same.

The example from wiki

```
String myString = null;
if (myString.equals("foobar")) { /* ... */ }
// This causes a NullPointerException in Java
```

With Yoda conditions:

```
String myString = null;
if ("foobar".equals(myString)) { /* ... */ }
// This is false, as expected
```

*Note that avoiding NullPointerException is not always an advantage. Covering them may cause other bugs or eat more time to debug your code.*

Answer (score 2):

While it is quite obvious that both `object == null` and `null == object` are identical, the reason for using the latter is **accidentally avoiding using an assignment instead of a comparison**.

In Java there the cases where this can happen are limited since only `boolean`s can be used in a test expression.

Consider

```
Object x = null;
int y = 0;

if (x = null) {}    //Error (Good catch)
if (null = x) {}    //Error (Of course, make no sense)


if (y = 0) {}    //Error (Good catch)
if (0 = y) {}    //Error (Of course, make no sense)
```

Now consider

```
Boolean x = false;
boolean y = false;

if ( x = false) {}   //OK (But maybe not what intended) 
if ( false = x) {}   //Error (Good catch) 

if ( y = false) {}   //OK (But maybe not what intended) 
if ( false = y) {}   //Error (Good catch)
```

So the *Yoda style* avoid making this kind of mistakes.

**Personally** I find *Yoda style* childish. Handling the assignment operator vs the equality operator is something that a programmer must be able to do, even when thinking about where they left their car keys.

Comment: Not only childish..dangerous some times :)